# Visio Document.Close Operation Disabled

Tags: vba, visio

I have some VBA code for Visio that saves out a document XML file then modifies the XML, and re-opens the file.  Then, the code closes the temporary XML file, but Visio is throwing an exception that "The Requested Operation is Presently Disabled", on the Document.Close method call.

I've not been able to find specific information on what conditions cause this exception when trying to close a document, and want to know if such information is available.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The operation appears to be disabled if the document being closed is not the active document.  In other words, activate the document and then close it.